# »getreu nach dem Katechismus« vs. getreu dem Katechismus

Tags: preposition, semantics

Ist das erste Beispiel, »getreu nach dem Katechismus«, das ich in *Buddenbrooks* gefunden habe, und deren englische Übersetzung (***true according to*** catechism) ein bisschen ungewöhnlich sein kann, mehr altmodisch als das zweite Beispiel, das ich ohne *nach* geschrieben habe?

Comment: Du hast keinen vollständigen Satz angegeben, deshalb ist es schwierig den ganzen Kontext zu griffen. Es scheint aber, dass es im ersten Fall "getreu" ein Adverb sei, und im zweiten Fall ein Adjektiv.

Comment: Ich denke, es gibt einen kleinen Bedeutungsunterschied "getreu nach dem" geht eher in die Richtung "nach dem Katechismus leben". Hingegen "getreu dem" geht eher in die Richtung "nach den Worten des Katechismus". Aber wie @Beta zurecht schreibt wäre es mehr Kontext hilfreich.

Comment: Context, please.

Comment: @IQV: Worauf gründet sich die Annahme, dass die eine Lesart stärker die Wortbedeutung betont? Für mich ist das Sprachesoterik - man will einen Unterschied finden und phantasiert sich was daher. Guter Wille + Sprachfühligkeit - leider nicht selten hier.

Answer (score 2):

It is in a very long sentence in the first chapter of the famous novel:

Und die kleine Antonie, achtjährig und zartgebaut, in einem Kleidchen aus ganz leichter changierender Seide, den hübschen Blondkopf ein wenig vom Gesichte des Großvaters abgewandt, blickte aus ihren graublauen Augen angestrengt nachdenkend und ohne etwas zu sehen ins Zimmer hinein, wiederholte noch einmal: "Was ist das", sprach darauf langsam: "Ich glaube, dass mich Gott", fügte, während ihr Gesicht sich aufklärte, rasch hinzu: "- geschaffen hat samt allen Kreaturen", war plötzlich auf glatte Bahn geraten und schnurrte nun, glückstrahlend und unaufhaltsam, den ganzen Artikel daher, getreu nach dem Katechismus, wie er soeben, Anno 1835, unter Genehmigung eines hohen und wohlweisen Senates, neu revidiert herausgegeben war.

In English: "...exactly as it is written in the catechism..."

Comment: Thank you. What is interesting is that not even Duded records "getreu" as an adverb. Only dict.cc does. I wonder why...

Comment: @user26328. In German all adjectives can be used as abverbs.

Comment: Without exception?

Comment: I cannot think of any exceptions.