# Zum Wort »wohlweise«

Tags: semantics

Ich habe dieses Wort [im gleichen Satz](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35686/getreu-nach-dem-katechismus-vs-getreu-dem-katechismus) von *Buddenbrooks* gefunden, aber ich kann es nicht verstehen, weil ich es nirgendwo finden kann.

Es gibt nur zwei andere Wörter, die ich in den Wörterbücher gefunden habe:

1. *[wohlweislich](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/wohlweislich)*, das nach diesem Wörterbuch *very wisely* bedeutet;
2. *[wahlweise](http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/wahlweise)*, das nach diesem Wörterbuch mehrere Bedeutung hat.

Aber nirgends kann ich *wohlweise* finden, als Mann dieses Wort benützt hat:

> [...] wie er soeben, anno 1835, unter Genehmigung eines hohen und
>   wohlweisen Senates, neu revidiert herausgegeben war.

Comment: Bei Thomas Mann kann man sich immer mal über ein paar veraltende oder veraltete Worte freuen. Ganz häufig ist das bei ihm ein Ironie-Signal.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Danke. Und ich bin mehr als begierig, alles das zu lernen.

Comment: Bist du Nichtmuttersprachler? Dann bist Du schon enorm weit fortgeschritten, wenn Du Thomas Mann liest :-)

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Ich bin nicht Muttersprachler dieser sehr schönen Sprache, die deine / Ihre ist. Und ich lese Thomas Mann, weil ich "schon enorm weit fortgeschritten" sein will...

Comment: Wenn Du auf der Suche nach weiteren Herausforderungen nach den Buddenbrooks bist: Thomas Mann: "Der Zauberberg". Und dann  Kant: "Kritik der reinen Vernunft", Max Horkheimer und Theodor W. Adorno: "Dialektik der Aufklärung" - Das versteht man auch als Muttersprachler*in nicht ohne Weiteres :-)

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Ja! Und Kants chef-d'œuvre vor allem, der ich bevor mein Tod im Original lesen können möchte. [As I can see from your profile that you are also into literature and philosophy, would you like us to begin an old-fashioned correspondence about these subjects via email? I'm looking for an intelligent person, such as yourself, to whom I could write in my as yet imperfect German, for the eventual Mann-like improvement of it. (As in former times, Cicero was the standard by which scholars got ever better at Latin, so is Mann my standard by which I constantly perfect my German)].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56443/discussion-between-jonathan-scholbach-and-user26328).

Comment: Das "im gleichen Satz" bezieht sich worauf? "Niirgends ... finden, als Mann dieses Wort benutzt hat". *Nirgends* ist ein räumliche, *als* eine zeitliche Spezifikation - das passt nicht zusammen. "Nirgends konnte ich das Wort finden, als Mann" wäre grammatisch richtig, macht aber keinen Sinn. "Nirgends finde ich ein Wörterbuch aus der Zeit, als ..."? Oder "In keinem Wörterbuch dieser Zeit finde ich ..."? Was ist gemeint?

Comment: @userunknown Danke für deine beißende Bemerkung.

Comment: Und was soll jetzt gefragt sein? Was ist mit "gleichem Satz" gemeint? Das waren Fragen zum Verständnis, keine beißenden Bemerkungen. Vielleicht bekäme die Frage mehr Upvotes wenn sie verbessert würde, statt sich bei Kritikern zu beschweren.

Comment: @userunknown I just don't understand why you changed my "im gleichen Satz" back into "in dem Satz." As far as I know, "in dem" is, for short, "im." Right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**wohlweise**

ist ein mittlerweile veraltetes und nicht mehr benutztes Adjektiv. In [Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW25737#XGW25737) findet man aber noch die Bedeutung:

> - als Höflichskeitsprädikat in mündlicher und schriftlicher Anrede vom 15. bis 18. Jh., vor allem in der Anrede von Stadtbehörden.
> - in freier Verwendung für 'sehr weise, sehr klug', häufig in ironisch abfälligem Sinne.

Nur vereinzelt kann man dieses Wort noch bis in die Mitte des letzten Jahrhunderts finden:

> In Hamburg, wo der hoch- und **wohlweise** Senat (Heine hat ihm attestiert, daß er es sei) augenblicklich dabei ist, von den Stadttauben ein Viertel ins Jenseits zu befördern, gibt es nur die beiden ersten Gruppen.<sup>Die Zeit 7.8.1959</sup>
>
> Der Macht wird allenfalls **wohlweise** zugeredet, sich in ihren guten Absichten nicht beirren zu lassen.<sup>Die Zeit 27.06.69</sup>

Comment: Danke. Alles klar jetzt.

Comment: @user26328 Dann mach doch den Haken an die Antwort; das ist hier so üblich, wenn die Antwort deine Frage klärt.

Comment: _wohlweislich_ als Adverb wird aber schon noch vereinzelt verwendet, ganz unironisch.

Comment: @Ingmar ja, das habe ich *wohlweislich* weggelassen, das der Fragesteller dies schon selbst gefunden hatte.

Comment: It is so interesting how my question has generated a lot fewer vote-ups than this wonderful answer, which after all would not have existed without it...

Comment: @user26328: unfortunately [it is how it is](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/422/does-careless-voting-or-non-voting-damage-this-site)... people tend to not vote much on questions. Most likely they simply forget about it. Nothing to worry about - the "best" question is what inspires for nice answers, and what causes traffic.